# Spring Boot connection to MySQL remote database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, remote-server

I am developing a application in Spring Boot. I am using phpMyAdmin (it is free at my university) database for persistence. I have my database in remote server. How to configure datasource for remote database connection?

Please help me configuring this in both property file as well as datasource bean configuration using annotations in my config class.

For example: Login username: `admin` , password: `root`

[image]

Comment: I need to use the database: "ii309808"

Comment: Sorry to break it down but phpMyAdmin is just an interface to interact with the database. You don't connect your spring app to phpMyAdmin. Also, show us what do you got so far and what research efforts have you made to figure out the solution to your problem.

Comment: The remote MySQL server must be listening on a publicly accessible IP address (usually my.ini has MySQL configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 – which will not see outside connections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe like

In file `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://lamp.ii.us.edu.pl:3306/ii309808
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

(`3306` is the default port number of MySQL database management system. Ask your system administrator if you can't connect via port `3306`)

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database